# UI class inheritance, super() not working correctly

Tags: python, wxwidgets

A wxwidgets UI class exists, that looks like this:

```
class mainFrame ( wx.Frame ):
     def __init__( self, parent ):
         # Constructor code
         # ...
         # ...
     # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
     def about_click( self, event ):
         event.Skip()
     def search_perform( self, event ):
         event.Skip()   
     def new_note_event( self, event ):
         event.Skip()   
     def save_note_event( self, event ):
         event.Skip()
```

I am able to directly construct an instance of this class and fill in the event-stubs, and it works, but I'm sure I'm not supposed to change the UI-code file at all, but use it as my base-class.

I tried using

```
class Main(mainFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainFrame, self).__init__(self, None)
```

The above doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed now. The `super()` call is **acting up**. When I reference the parent class by name instead, it works.

The way I am using the UI class is

```
class Main(mainFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        mainFrame.__init__(self, None) # using super().__init__(self, None) fails
    def about_click( self, event ):
        print("AboutDialog")

def main():
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    frame = Main()
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

`super()` **does not work** for old-style classes at all. It works only for [new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) which inherit from either `object` or other new-style classes.